Filter data.frame rows based in two columns and an external vector in R
I have a data frame with position ranges (Initial and Final) and a Position vector like:
df <- data.frame(
   row = c("A", "B", "C", "D"), 
   Initial = c(10, 26, 48, 69), 
   Final = c(23, 47, 64, 80))

  row Initial Final
1   A      10    23
2   B      26    47
3   C      48    64
4   D      69    80

Vector:
Position <- c(32, 54, 82)

I would like to filter rows that include a position that belongs to the vector. The output would be:
  row Initial Final
1   B      26    47
2   C      48    64

Please note the last position did not match to the df Initial-Final position range. Is there a tidyverse solution?

inner_join(df, data.frame(Position), join_by(Initial < Position, Final > Position))

  row Initial Final Position
1   B      26    47       32
2   C      48    64       54


subset(df, mapply(\(x,y)any(x < Position & y > Position), df$Initial, df$Final))
  row Initial Final
2   B      26    47
3   C      48    64


> df[sapply(seq_len(nrow(df)), \(row) any(Position %in% seq(df$Initial[row], df$Final[row])) ), ]
  row Initial Final
2   B      26    47
3   C      48    64


library(dplyr)
df |>
  filter(rowSums(sapply(Position, between, Initial, Final)) > 0)
#   row Initial Final
# 1   B      26    47
# 2   C      48    64

The largest difference between Onyambu's use of mapply (over the frame columns) and my use of sapply (over the Position vector) is that I'm assuming that Position is smaller than the frame. If you find that nrow(df) > length(Position), it will be (slightly) more efficient to use
df |>
  filter(mapply(function(a, b) any(between(Position, a, b)), Initial, Final))

which is simply a dplyr-ized version of Onyambu's base-R answer.

Out of all these solutions, I still could not figure out how to not use O(n*m) to solve the problem.

The only way to do better (iiuc) is to compare one position at a time and early-exit once one is found. At that point, the order of Position is meaningful, and I don't know that it will asymptotically do much better than O(n*log(m)) or such ... unless you're lucky enough to hit Position[1] every single time. (But for this notional lower-O solution, I think R is not the best language ...) @Onyambu

I came up with a cut method, but assumes that the intervals are disjoint ie no overlaps and increasing in order. This is faster as it is O(n)  if I am not mistaken.

can you bench::mark that? You may need to grow the data 2-3 orders of magnitude to get comparable/meaningful benchmarks

Yes the cut method works way faster than the rest but slower than the left_join. left_join is the fastest. Meaning if we used a data.table it will be fastest

(1) Over to you, the join idea was yours to begin with, you should be the one to recommend it. (2) We are jumping to the conclusion that the user has gobs of data where this amount of fine-tuning is going to be measurable. Still, over to you. Nice find, though!

Thanks to all of you that replied, great insights, I am learning a lot here. All the solutions from Jilber Urbina, Onyambu and r2evans works fine for me. But I have to admit I will take the join solution for my problem as it also include the position in the df. Thanks all of you once again.
